# How to configure nginx to pass proxy to tomcat on CentOS

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have installed nginx on my machine which has CentOS and a tomcat application server on another machine which has CentOS too. Now I want to configure nginx to pass proxy to my tomcat application server.

tomcat application server's IP is : 192.168.0.xxx:8080
nginx server IP is : 192.168.0.xxx.

Now when I sent requests to nginx it should be passed to the tomcat application server.

I need all steps to configuration for proxy pass from nginx to tomcat.

Comment: And I need free beer. However, you probably shouldn't treat your peers as your personal wageslave. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. Furthermore, your question is off-topic and should rather go to http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Since your Tomcat connector uses HTTP protocol you can try someting like this:

1. Create normal site listening on port 80 (or 443 for standard SSL)
2. Paste this code which redirects all requests to port 8080
3. Customize below config to your needs - http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

   ```
   location /
   {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.0.xxx:8080;
   proxy_set_header Host      $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }
   ```

If you however want to use AJP connectors, consider using Apache with mod_jk.

Comment: should i write this configuration in nginx.conf

Comment: you should have conf.d or site-enabled directory in /etc/nginx
This is the right place for creating sites
If you however want full example using nginx.conf see
http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

Comment: i have done the same configuration but it still show me error like " 502 Bad Gateway"